# How do I clone a gerrit repository with the /refs/for/* config options added automatically?

Tags: git, gerrit

My company uses gerrit and we have many repositories. Every time a new repository is cloned, we need to manually add the `push = HEAD:refs/for/master` line to our git config. Is there any way to configure our projects so this line gets added automatically when the project is cloned?

Similarly, it would be nice to ensure that `createchangeid = true` is added so that it doesn't need to be in the user's global config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell people to use your script to clone, where your script reads, e.g.:

```
#! /bin/sh -e
git clone "$@"
[insert all the git config commands you like here]
```

Make sure this script is executable (`chmod +x`).

The usage of this script will be the same as the usage of `git clone`.  If you do write such a script and install it somewhere so that your users' `$PATH` will find it, and if you name this script `git-xyzzy`, they can run `git xyzzy <clone-arguments>` and that will run this script, as if it were a standard part of Git (though obviously, since you wrote it yourself, it's not).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I implemented this and it seems to work. Created a gist here for other people to use. https://gist.github.com/aeisenberg/b9e0b1ca47db44b306fd058e377c46ae I am not much of a bash genius, so any comments on making this better would be appreciated.